# git checkout branch - now have duplicate

Tags: git

Now I have this

```
[root@RUSH pmtsystem]# git branch -a
  master
  remotes/origin/upgrade-to-mpdf56
* rush
  remotes/origin/HEAD -> origin/master
  remotes/origin/atc
  remotes/origin/master
  remotes/origin/pmt
  remotes/origin/rush
  remotes/origin/upgrade-to-mpdf56
```

The idea was to checkout remotes/origin/upgrade-to-mpdf56 but this went horribly wrong. Can it be fixed?

Comment: Is this a continuation of a previous question? Please provide some context.

Comment: How come there are two `remotes/origin/upgrade-to-mpdf56` ? Confused.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The right way to get a copy of a remote repo would be something like:

```
git clone -b upgrade-to-mpdf56 git@foo.example.com/path
```

To put your local cpoy on that branch and merge your diffs do:

```
git checkout -m upgrade-to-mpdf56
```

Use Schleis suggestion to delete the local evil branch.

Answer (score 3):

You should be able to do `git branch -d remotes/origin/upgrade-to-mpdf56`  As you can't delete a remote branch in this manner.

You can also edit your .git/config file and remove the entry for the branch there as well.